# Date range picker start date & locale format not setting in angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, daterangepicker

Start Date & Format not setting in date range picker, please find the code below

Issue: Start date and format not bind properly in the view

**In Controller**

```
$scope.pngDatePicker = { startDate: moment().subtract(1, "days"), endDate: moment() };
$scope.pngDatePickerOpts = {
    autoApply: true,
    locale: { format: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }, 
    dateLimit: {
        months: 3
    },
    maxDate: moment()
};
```

**In view**

```
<input type="daterange" data-ng-required="true" date-range-picker ng-model="pngDatePicker" options="pngDatePickerOpts" id="dateRange" class="form-control date-picker">
```

Output:

[Date range Picker Output in angularjs view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8QNW.jpg)

Comment: created a plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/T3l9fSs7NONaaT5qbHxi?p=preview, everything seems to work properly, please specify what is wrong

Comment: I have the same example from https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker, which is working fine. But when i try those locale format, set start date are not working in my angularjs application.

Comment: so, what is not setting in angular view? I see start time in the pop down calendar, dates are formatted as configured

Comment: 1) Format set in controller is 'YYYY-MM-DD', but in view it is MM/DD/YYYY 2) startDate: moment().subtract(1, "days") ==> Startdate set as 1 day before current day,  but in view it is current day

Comment: please upload your code somewhere or update my plunker, so I can check and hopefully fix it